# Getting ORA-00957: duplicate column name, while creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to make a table, but i am getting duplicate column name error.

My Oracle Query is following

```
     CREATE TABLE CCILDBDEV.TRN_FYC_FWD_UP
        (
            Tran_Reference    varchar2(100)    ,
            Related_Tran_Ref    varchar2(100)    ,
            Client_Name    varchar2(100)    ,
            Client_ID    varchar2(100)    ,
            Transaction_Type    varchar2(100)    ,
            Trade_Date    varchar2(100)    ,
            Trade_Time_Stamp    varchar2(100)    ,
            Buy_Currency_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            Buy_Currency_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            Sell_Currency_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            Sell_Currency_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            Exchange_Rate    varchar2(100)    ,
            Value_Dates_From    varchar2(100)    ,
            Value_Dates_To    varchar2(100)    ,
            Premium_Fwd_premium    varchar2(100)    ,
            Spot_Rate    varchar2(100)    ,
            Purpose    varchar2(100)    ,
            Remarks    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTILSCAN_Trade_Date    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTIL_SCAN_Settlement_Date    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTILSCAN_Buy_Cur_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTILSCAN_Buy_Cur_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTILSCAN_Sell_Cur_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            UTILSCAN_Sell_Cur_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            Cons_Currency_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            Cons_Currency_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            SCAN_Rate    varchar2(100)    ,
            Swap_Cost    varchar2(100)    ,
            Cons_Settlement_Indicator    varchar2(100)    ,
            Outsd_Buy_Currency_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            Outd_Buy_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            Outsd_Sell_Currency_Code    varchar2(100)    ,
            Outsd_Sell_Amount    varchar2(100)    ,
            Extended_Expiry_Date    varchar2(100)    ,
            Rep_Date_and_Time    varchar2(100)    ,
            Mat_Date_and_Time    varchar2(100)    ,
            Deal_Status    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT1    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT1    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT2    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT2    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT3    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT3    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT4    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT4    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT5    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT5    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT6    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT6    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT7    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT7    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT8    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT8    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT9    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT9    varchar2(100)    ,

            PYMNTDT10    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT10    varchar2(100)    ,


            PYMNTDT11    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT11    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT12    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT12    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT13    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT13    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT14    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT14    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT15    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT15    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT16    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT16    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT17    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT17    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT18    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT18    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT19    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT19    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT20    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT20    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT21    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT21    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT22    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT22    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT23    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT23    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT24    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT24    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT25    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT25    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT26    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT26    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT27    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT27    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT28    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT28    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT29    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT29    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT30    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT30    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT31    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT31    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT32    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT32    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT33    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT33    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT34    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT34    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT35    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT35    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT36    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT36    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT37    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT37    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT38    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT38    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT39    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT39    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT40    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT40    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT41    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT41    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT42    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT42    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT43    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT43    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT44    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT44    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT45    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT45    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT46    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT46    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT47    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT47    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT48    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT48    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT49    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT49    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT50    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT50    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT51    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT51    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTDT52    varchar2(100)    ,
            PYMNTAMNT52    varchar2(100)    ,

            UPLOADED_USER      NUMBER(4),
            UPLOADED_DATE      DATE,
            REMARKS            VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
        );
```

While running the above given query, The following error occurred And I don't know Where I did wrong. Please help me anyone
    Error: Getting ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Comment: How to find the duplicate column easily? Is there any possible to find by using any tool?

Comment: Your SQL tool should point you to the line where the error occurs. Also: having 52 "PYMNTAMNT" and "PYMNTDT" columns is most probably a really bad design. Create a proper one-to-many relationship. And a columns with `Date_and_Time` in it should be defined as a `date` or timestamp. ***Never*** store dates as `varchar`. And a column with the name `amount` or `rate`  in it should be defined as `number`. ***Never*** store numbers as `varchar`

Comment: You have `REMARKS` and `Remarks` duplicating the column.

Comment: @Deinum Yes. Thank you for your response

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your suggestions and time. I am beginner to SQL query, I will Correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Remarks` is the duplicate column here.

To find duplicates easily, run the query in Developer first. It will show you the line number that is hitting with an error message.

Take the line number and catch the column name. Use any Text editor to search for the column name. If you encounter the name somewhere delete it.

End of it.

Answer (score 4):

The duplicate is remarks. Different capitalization, but that doesn't matter unless you use double quotes, which would be a bad idea.

You may want to rethink your table structure, payment dates and amounts shouldn't be kept in so many columns. There are other problems, but that is the most obvious one.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `remarks` columns

```
REMARKS VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
Remarks varchar2(100) ,
```